# Copy and paste items from hidden sheets 2, 3 and 4 into sheet 1 if specific option chosen

Tags: excel, vba

I am hoping that someone might be able to assist with a vba code that I am trying to apply to my workbook. I have created a dropdown list of 3 options in cell a1 on sheet 1 of my work book.  Ideally, when an option is selected it will automatically pull the cell format, contents, and codes from another work sheet and apply it to sheet 1. So ideally the code would generate the following results:

```
Text "Option 1" is selected from drop down in a1 - sheet 2 content copy and 
pastes in sheet 1 starting at cell b1
Text "Option 2" is selected from drop down in a1 - sheet 3 content copy and 
pastes in sheet 1 starting at cell b1
Text "Option 3" is selected from drop down in a1 - sheet 4 content copy and 
pastes in sheet 1 starting at cell b1
```

Comment: All you need is the `Worksheet_Change`-event and a simple `If ... Then ... ElseIf ... Then ...`-function and the build in macro recorder. If you have a specific problem you are free to come back and ask again. Then you also will get more specific answers. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the below macro to your dropdown list and change the sheet name accordingly.

```
Sub DropDown1_Change()
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = 1 Then
        Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = 2 Then
        Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = 3 Then
        Sheets("Sheet4").UsedRange.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Select
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks